# CUPS. Printer "pending" mode

Tags: printing

After sending the image to print, the printer puts the job in the "pending" queue and prints it in a few minutes or immediately after restarting CUPS with the command "sudo service cups restart". Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: can you add the output of `lpstat -p`, while the job is pending, to your question

Comment: lp -d MITSU /home/mbs/ptoto4print.jpg
request id id MITSU-34 ((1-files))
lp -d MITSU /home/mbs/photo4print.jpg
request id id MITSU-34 ((1-files))
lpstat -p
printer MITSU now printing MITSU-34, enabled since Sun 04 June 2017 09:47:38 BST
 Sending data

Comment: The printer prints the image 5 minutes after the command "lp -d MITSU /home/mbs/ptoto4print.jpg". Or printing occurs immediately after two consecutive commands:
lp -d MITSU /home/mbs/ptoto4print.jpg
Sudo service cups restart
The printer is Mitsubishi CPD70DW. It runs on Ubuntu 16.04 (gutenprint 5.2.12 + Solomon Peachy drivers set: http://www.peachyphotos.com/blog/posts/201610061508-mitsubishi-cp-d70-family-working/)